How to show that 1-dimensional affine group over F is a split extension of subgroup of translations by an abelian subgroup.
I am working on this problem where first it was asked to show that the set of translations $t_{1\beta}, \beta \in F$ forms a transitive normal abelian subgroup $T$ of $AGL_1(F)$. This was trivial, I proved that $T = \{ t_{1\beta} | t_{1\beta}:\alpha \mapsto \alpha + \beta, \alpha, \beta \in F\}$ is normal abelian subgroup as we do and transitive by using the definition that a transitive group must have only one orbit, i.e., $\alpha^T = F, \forall \alpha \in F$.
But then it is asked to show that $AGL_1(F)$ is a split extension of $T$ by an abelian subgroup. I only know that I need to show there exists a short exact sequence $1 \rightarrow N \xrightarrow{\pi} AGL_1(F) \xrightarrow{\psi} T \rightarrow 1$ where $\pi(N)$ is a normal subgroup of $AGL_1(F)$ and $\frac{AGL_1(F)}{N} \cong T$, but how do I proceed further and also how can I show it is split? Any hints?
I actually have less to no idea about exact sequences and came to know about this while going through Dixon-Mortimer for an undergraduate project work I am currently doing. Even if there is a short explanation on exact-sequences and how to show splitting, it would be of great help. Thank you!
